# Survival analysis of a population - Proportional hazards

Tags: survival, proportional-hazards

first time here :) here's my problem. I developed an agent-based model (ABM) that I used to generate some data that I would like to analyze, but I couldn’t find a methodology that I can be confident about. My ABM simulates an environment in which a majority community (that speak language A) and a minority community (speaking A and B) coexist. I look at communication among individuals speaking different languages and at the implications in terms of decline of one community with respect to the other. The basic idea is that if minority speakers speak A too often, they slowly lose language B and are assimilated in the majority group. The parameters of the ABM include variables such as the frequency of mixed couples (generating babies who only speak the majority language) or how willing minority speakers are to show that they speak the minority language. I simulated numerous scenarios with different settings and collected the number of time-steps before the minority was completely absorbed over a maximum horizon of 1000 time-steps. I tried to use Cox proportional hazard regression to estimate a survival function, but it turns out that the PH assumption is violated. Thank you very much to all those who will read my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to CV.

Why are you using Cox (or any similar method) on the ABM results?  You could use the ABM results themselves, couldn't you? That is, from the ABM, you can get a bunch of runs of each situation and use those runs to estimate what you want.

However, if you do need survival analysis with non-proportional hazards, there are a lot of different methods. They have been discussed here many times (search on https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/survival) and also in many books and papers.

If those don't answer your question, you can ask a new one with more details of why they don't.